How can I replace JS eval function with more secure function?
How can I replace JS eval function with more secure solution?
const textarea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
const tooltip2 = document.querySelectorAll(".tooltip2");
const hiddenTooltip = document.querySelectorAll(".hiddenTooltip");

let replaced = 'textareaValue';
for (let i = 0; i < tooltip2.length; i++) {
    replaced += '.replace(/' + tooltip2[i].innerText + '/g,' + "'" + hiddenTooltip[i].innerText + "'" + ')'
}
replaced += ';';

textarea.value = eval( replaced );

This code works, eval function changes string to expression, but I read that's not secure. I should have something like this:
let replaced = textareaValue.replace(/kga/g,'całkowite opracowanie ubytku, selektywne wytrawianie, UB, Gradia A3').replace(/ksc/g,'scaling nad i poddziąsłowy, fluoryzacja na łyżkach').replace(/ksn/g, 'scaling naddziąsłowy, fluoryzacja na łyżkach').replace(/ksp/g, 'scaling poddziąsłowy, fluoryzacja na łyżkach').replace(/kwg/g, 'całkowite opracowanie ubytku, wypełnienie glasjonomerowe');

I have PHP code to add or remove shortcuts dynamically. My PHP code works.
I tried trick with new Function, but it doesn't work.
textarea.value = new Function('return ' + replaced)();

Could you give me a solution to my problem?

"I should have something like this:" - Is that the code you want to execute?  Did you try?  It's not at all clear to me what the "trick with new Function" is meant to accomplish, or even why eval was used in the first place.  If the goal is to call .replace() a few times on a string, why can't you simply do that?

You should use neither eval nor Function. Construct the dynamic regular expressions that you want to pass to replace using new RegExp()!

@David I tried it, let replaced = textareaValue.replace(... works, but I need shortcuts like kga, kgh and etc added dynamically. I have php page where I can add or remove shortcuts and their names. Eval function works, but I read that it's slow and not secure.

@Mark: It sounds like you're just looking for new Regexp() to build your regular expressions from strings, so you can dynamically build those strings.

You don't need eval for this at all. Just call .replace() repeatedly in the loop:
for (let i = 0; i < tooltip2.length; i++) {
    const search = new RegExp(tooltip2[i].innerText, 'g');
    const replacement = hiddenTooltip[i].innerText;

    textareaValue = textareaValue.replace(search, replacement);
}


https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll
